# como usar una función para determinar un máximo dadas dos condiciones y dos valores de entrada

Tags: python

Un pliego de papel albanene sirve para realizar 12 tarjetas en tarjetería española. Además, un plumón para tarjetería española sirve para hacer 35 tarjetas. Realiza un programa que utilice una función y que indique cuántas tarjetas de tarjetería española se pueden hacer máximo dada una cantidad de pliegos de papel albanene (número entero) y de plumones (número entero).

Por ejemplo, si se tienen 70 pliegos pero solo 2 plumones, solo se pueden hacer 70 tarjetas como máximo. Dentro de la función, ¿cuantas variables tendría que usar?

```
def cuantas(pliegos,plumon):
  
def main():
    #escribe tu código abajo de esta línea
    pass
    papel = int(input("Dame la cantidad de pliegos de papel albanene: "))
    plumones = int(input("Dame la cantidad de plumones: "))

    tarjetas = cuantas(papel,plumones)
    print(tarjetas)


    
 
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Bienvenido Luis Fernando a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Razonemos juntos, tienes 70 pliegos de papel con los que podrías hacer 12 x 70 tarjetas, sin embargo solo tienes 2 plumones, por lo que, aunque te sobre papel estás limitado a 2 x70 tarjetas.  Esto lo tienes que hacer con cualquier valor que reciba la función y siemplemente quedarte con el valor mínimo de tarjetas que surja

Comment: Trata de codificarlo, y si tienes alguna duda concreta agrégala a la pregunta, darte el ejercicio ya escrito no te hará ningún favor.

Comment: tengo que usar un condicional? 
` ` `
 tarjetasXpapel = pliegos * 12
 tarjetasXplumon = plumon * 35
    if
` ` `

Comment: Lo único que tienes que hacer es pensar, si te dan 1000 pliegos pero 2 plumones solo puedes hacer 70. La cantidad maxima que puedes hacer es de `num_plumones*35` si el número de pliegos que te dan es menor que eso entonces lo máximo que puedes hacer es la misma cantidad de pliegos, todo tu problema se resuelve en una línea de código

Comment: `return (num_plumones*35 if num_pliegos>=num_plumones*35 else num_pliegos)`

Answer (score -1):

```
def tarjeteria(papel,plumones):
    calc_papel = papel * 12
    calc_plumones = plumones * 35
    if calc_papel<calc_plumones:
        return calc_papel
    else:
        return calc_plumones
papel = int(input("Dame la cantidad de pliegos de papel albanene:"))
plumones = int(input("Dame la cantidad de plumones:"))
print("El numero maximo es:",tarjeteria(papel,plumones))
```

Comment: En lugar de escribir improperios, **explica tu respuesta**. Pulsa en [edit] para corregirla. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. [es.so] no es un repositorio de código, ni un sitio similar a _El Rincón del Vago_. Por último, revisa el [Código de Conducta](/conduct) :)